# partition drive not appearing in explorer

Tags: windows, macos, hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

I originally had a 2 terabyte hard drive partitioned as a 256GB OSX partition, and a 1600~ Dynamic disc (shows up as two blocks on disc management)

After i went on disc utility to delete my hackintosh drive i reformatted my 256gb OSX partition as exFAT and restarted to boot into windows 8.1.

When i checked explorer to access my 1600 drive (dynamic disk) i couldn't see it. i checked disk partition and saw to my horror that the dynamic disk which was previously two blocks now shows as a single block basic disk partition. This obviously means that i can no longer access the drive or see it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/stqWX.png), i cancelled the the reformat of the ex partition to try and fix this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mafgi.png

I want to be able to pull off or access the data on the drive partition, does anyone know how to do this? preferably turn it back into the dynamic disk it is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to get your files back first (to a separate physical drive, of course).

If you are certain that you have them all, you could then try TestDisk to restore the partition table.

If you want to be really careful, and you have a spare disk of at least the same capacity, you could do a device-level copy by using [dd](https://langui.sh/2011/04/02/using-dd-in-os-x/) - investigate more thoroughly than just that article.

Comment: yes i found photorec whilst trying to fix it (qphotorec which i believe is just a gui version of photorec?) and it seems to be stuck

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix a dynamic and non-dynamic partition on the same disk - I don't know how you do it but this is an unsupported configuration that should not be possible.

It sounds like what has happened is OS X has overwritten the dynamic disk metadata, causing Windows to be unable to load the dynamic configuration. This may be because of the way LDM "retains" bootable partitions on dynamic disks (using a 'fake' partition that points close to, but not exactly at an overlayed dynamic volume).

If your dynamic volume was a simple volume (one extent, no striping, etc.) then most data recovery software should be able to get the data off it. You should *not* attempt to "turn it back into the dynamic disk" in situ. The safe course of action would be to copy your data off, re-partition and reformat, then move your data back on.

That said [R-Studio](http://www.data-recovery-software.net/) has fairly advanced capabilities even in free/trial mode including reliably detecting locations of undefined partitions, and allowing you to clone arbitrary disk extents as partitions. If you have a spare 2TB disk, or 2TB space elsewhere you could store a VHD file, you can use R-Studio to convert the raw data block into a standard partition you can directly use in Windows.